# IDEA: How to switch between quotes in current cursor position

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to have an easy one command way to switch between quotes style in IDEA.

```
"Sample test" => 'Sample test'
'Sample test' => "Sample test"
```

I know I can select all the text with quotes and type `"` to change from single quotes, for example.

I can use `CMD-Up` few times to expand selection and after that change surrounding.
But It is too many actions to do for such small change.

Maybe Idea have a better way to change the current quote style?

Or any plugins for that?

Answer (score 2):

Without plugins you can:

1. Use `Alt-Enter` context action with your cursor in the string and select "Replace single-quoted string with double-quoted string" (or vice versa). This will only apply to the string where your cursor is.
2. Update your code style settings in whatever language you are using to be the type of quotes you want and then apply your code style with `Cmd-Alt-L`. This has the side-effect of potentially applying code style not related to quote type if other code doesn't match your configured style.

Comment: Thank you! `Alt-Enter` is really useful option. But it still not one-command

Comment: You may record macros and assign shortcut for it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html